# Importing SVG images into SVG file

Tags: svg

I want to display an external SVG file in an SVG document.

My external file is here: [SVG_example_markup_grid.svg](https://magico.co.za/SVG_example_markup_grid.svg)
The file I want to use to display the images is here:[vport.svg](https://magico.co.za/vport.svg)

The only technique that works (in Firefox, anyway) is the `<use>` tag and then only if I insert an `id="someID"` parameter into the external file and add "#someID" onto the end of the href parameter in the display file. `<use href="SVG_example_markup_grid.svg#someID"`.

However, the SVG_example_markup_grid.svg file has elements that start at x="-70" and y="-70" and all elements drawn at coordinates less than zero are not rendered.

How can I get around this?

I need the external file to be displayed inside a clipping rectangle at a possibly reduced scale.

Comment: Use a viewBox on the use element.

Comment: Thanks: that works. Only problem is that I don't know the cartesian extents of the base svg file prior to it's construction. I'm sure that I could work around it though, so thanks for your valuable input.